# Functional binding is disabled due to the presense of @EnableBinding annotation in your configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I upgraded spring boot to 2.3.0.RELEASE and the spring boot application is stuck at the last line and it never starts. Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
09:26 23:57:52.276 [main            ] [WARN] [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration] - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
09:26 23:57:52.547 [main            ] [INFO] [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver] - Exposing 20 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
09:26 23:57:52.597 [task-scheduler-1] [INFO] [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
09:26 23:57:52.764 [main            ] [INFO] [springfox.documentation.spring.web.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping] - Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
09:26 23:57:52.810 [main            ] [WARN] [com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource] - No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
09:26 23:57:52.810 [main            ] [INFO] [com.netflix.config.sources.URLConfigurationSource] - To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
09:26 23:57:54.873 [main            ] [INFO] [org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionBindingRegistrar] - Functional binding is disabled due to the presense of @EnableBinding annotation in your configuration
```

Comment: Please take a thread dump (kill -3 or using jstack) and share the output

Comment: Thanks! @Andy Wilkinson. I see a datasource creation function was missing Bean annotation and the application starts fine after adding Bean annotation on the method.

Answer (score 0):

I see a datasource creation method was missing @Bean annotation and the application starts fine after adding @Bean annotation